# How to put 2 query parameter in Talend Data Stewardship TQL query?

Tags: talend

In Talend Data Stewardship UI, we can put the TQL query to filter our data.

For example, I can put `creationDate >= 1682265600000` , or I can put `creationDate < 1682352000000` , put anyone of this in my query, I can get my result filter correctly.

For example, when I put `creationDate >= 1682265600000`, my record with `"creationDate": 1682361299087` will be selected.

And when I put `creationDate < 1682352000000` as query, then my record with `"creationDate": 1682361299087` will NOT be selected.

This is correct because 1682361299087 is greater than 1682352000000.

However, if I combine 2 query together, `creationDate >= 1682265600000 AND creationDate < 1682352000000`, I expected my record wont be selected, but its still selected.

The following is my screen shot of TDS query filter input:
[image]

And the following is the result in response body:

[image]

May I know which part I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause, in the query, I need to use `and` instead of `AND`.